# How do I use the prometheus "max" function and not lose the stat name and labels?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm using prometheus and am trying to get the maximum of two stats and find I'm losing the name and labels for the result.

For this promql query...

sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{mode=`user`}

The result is...

sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{category="system", instance="ns_server", job="general", mode="user", name="sys_cpu_host_seconds_total"}      3065880.72

For this promql query...

sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{mode=`sys`}

The result is...

sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{category="system", instance="ns_server", job="general", mode="sys", name="sys_cpu_host_seconds_total"}      1760763.05

When I obtain the maximum of the two using this promql query...

max(sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{mode=`sys`} or sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{mode=`user`})

The result is the following. How do I keep the stat name and labels in the result?
{}      3065880.72

Answer (score 3):

### by(), without()

The [**max()** aggregation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) (as well other aggregations) on its own discards all the labels and the metric name, and provides the aggregated result with no labels, since the max is selected across all the time series. It is no longer the `sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{mode=sys}` or `sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{mode=user}`, but the max value of them.

To control the labels in an aggregation you have 2 clauses to use:

1. **without()** - removes the listed labels from the result vector, while all other labels are preserved in the output

F.e. if he metric has 2 labels `mode` and `job` and you want to preserve the `job` label while take the `max` among `mode`-s you could use:

```
max(sys_cpu_host_seconds_total)without(mode)
```

The result vector will return the max value preserving ****all*** the rest labels but the `mode`*:

```
{job='demo-1'} 3065880.72
{job='demo-2'} 1760763.05
```

2. **by()** - does the opposite and drops labels that are not listed in the by clause, even if their label values are identical between all elements of the vector

F.e. if he metric has 2 labels `mode` and `job` and you want to preserve the `job` label while take the `max` among `job`-s you could use:

```
max(sys_cpu_host_seconds_total)by(job)
```

The result vector will be the same, but it contains ****only*** the `job` label*:

```
{job='demo-1'} 3065880.72
{job='demo-2'} 1760763.05
```

### "__name__" label

The trick with the metric name is that internally it is a label with the special name of `"__name__"`. So you could use it to preserve the metric name if you really need it:

```
max(sys_cpu_host_seconds_total)by(__name__, job)
```

The result vector will "preserve" the metric name, however it's just a trick since the result is no longer the metric you aggregate on, but the aggregation result:

```
sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{job='demo-1'} 3065880.72
sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{job='demo-2'} 1760763.05
```

### topk(1, ...)

`topk` and `bottomk` are different from other aggregators in that a subset of the input samples, including the original labels, are returned in the result vector, so you coul use this trick *to preserve all the labels along with the name*:

```
topk(1, sys_cpu_host_seconds_total)
```

The result vector will "preserve" all the labels along with the metric name:

```
sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{mode='sys', job='demo-1'} 3065880.72
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [topk](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk) for selecting the metric with the maximum value:

```
topk(1, 
  sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{mode="sys"}
  or sys_cpu_host_seconds_total{mode="user"}
)
```

Note that `topk(k, q)` query can return more than `k` time series when this query is used for building a graph in Grafana. This is because `topk(k, q)` independently selects top `k` series per each timestamp displayed on the graph. If you want up to `k` series with max malues to be displayed on the graph, then take a look at [topk_max](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk_max), [topk_avg](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#topk_avg) and other `topk_*` functions in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) - this is PromQL-compatible query language in [Prometheus-like system I work on](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/).